# No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg' on MacOS in Python OpenAI Whisper

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, apple-silicon, openai-whisper

I am using MacOS (Apple Silicon) and I am trying to use the whisper module from OpenAI in Python. My code is this:

```
import whisper

file_path = "4547.mp3"
model = whisper.load_model("base")

result = model.transcribe(file_path)
print(result["text"])
```

When running that code I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg': 'ffmpeg'
```

I think it is because Python is looking in the wrong folder for ffmpeg and therefore can't find it, but I don't know how to fix that if that is the issue.

I have installed homebrew and used the command 'brew install ffmpeg' and it has successfully installed with no errors. I have tried uninstalling ffmpeg and reinstalling it, uninstalling open_whisper and reinstalling it, installing ffmpeg-python, and doing pip (and pip3) install ffmpeg.

Comment: Add `ffmpeg` to `$PATH`.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Answer (score 1):

for me (Python 3.9.13, Mac OS) the issue is resolved by adding the following lines:

```
ffmpeg_path = "/path/to/ffmpeg"  
os.environ['PATH'] += f':{os.path.dirname(ffmpeg_path)}'
```

Where "/path/to/ffmpeg" is replaced by the actual path. You can find this by entering "which ffmpeg" in your terminal (assuming you have already installed ffmpeg)